# Remove DIV tag using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I remove a DIV with a specific value?

```
<div value="0" class="task_row"></div>
```

I want to remove the above div which has value 0.

Comment: Are you using a javascript library? Is jQuery going to be an acceptable answer? If so, you can do this if jQuery: $('[value="0"]').remove();

Comment: value is not a valid attribute of the div tag.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As Ben Rowe points out in the comments, `value` is not a valid attribute of the div tag. And both the jQuery solution and the solution that uses `getElementsByTagName()` has to iterate through a list, which is bad for performance. I think that creating an `id` attribute instead is a better option:

```
<div id="task_row_0" class="task_row"></div>
```

And then you can just do:

```
var div = document.getElementById("task_row_" + taskId);
div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
```

Comment: Let's be realistic here. There's zero need for jQuery to do something simple such as this.

Comment: Let's be even more realistic here. Tons of people use jQuery, so if they're already using it, why wouldn't they go for a simple single line of code. [+1 for this answer though because I happen to not be using jQuery at the moment]

Comment: jQuery eats computer resources and hangs browsers when opened on several tabs, so please dont use it!

Answer (score 4):

this is jquery code )):

```
$('div').each(function(){
  if($(this).attr('value') == '0'){
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i = divs.length; i; i -= 1) {
    if (divs[i].getAttribute('value') == 0) {
        divs[i].parentNode.removeChild(divs[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I use your snippet code, but it had error. initial value for `i` and end condition are not valid

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: Nevermind - Zhasulan beat me to it. :P**

With jQuery -

```
$('div').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('value') == '0') {
        $(this).hide();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to jQuery/JavaScript you can achieve it via CSS only -

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r9wfk4vj/)**

```
div[value="0"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Or via jQuery using attribute selector:

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r9wfk4vj/1/)**

```
$("div[value='0']").hide(); /*.remove() as per your requirement*/
```