# How to hide the html tag when its empty

Tags: html, grails, tags, gsp

A gsp file contain code as below

```
<div class="alphabet">
    <div class="a" >
        <kbd></kbd>
    </div>

    <div class="b" >
        <kbd></kbd>
    </div>
</div>
```

How is it possible to hide the `kbd` tag when it is empty? Assume the value for kbd comes from a javascript.Possibly done in gsp itself.

What I mean empty is

```
Empty (should hide)
<kbd></kbd>

Has value
kbd>Testing</kbd>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean removing a tag using javascript? It's been discussed many times, for example here: [Remove DIV tag using Javascript or Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755546/remove-div-tag-using-javascript-or-jquery)

If you can do that in GSP (so you have value before javascript) you can use `<g:if>` tag

Comment: I would like to it be done from gsp. How should I check for empty with <g:if>? I find the kbd node by class in javascript and put value using .html.

Comment: If you set value using javascript, you have to hide also using javascript. GSP is evaluated before and have access only to model passed from controller

Comment: By the way, maybe you should look into framework like AngularJS which keeps view state and very easily allows you to have such functionality, for example using 'ng-if' of Angular 1.x