# Remove div tag content

Tags: javascript, html

How to remove div tag content  on click  **x** (using javascript) ?

```
<div id="rang">
<div class="clsrng"><span class="spnrng">one</span><span class="clsrng">x</span></div>
<div class="clsrng"><span class="spnrng">two</span><span class="clsrng">x</span></div>
<div class="clsrng"><span class="spnrng">three</span><span class="clsrng">x</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use DOM traverse methods and get the closest div and remove it

Comment: Try adding css property `display: none` on-click event

Comment: If you can post the code you have tried so far, we could help further :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove DIV tag using Javascript or Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755546/remove-div-tag-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: which div do you want to clear with each x?

Comment: @climon <div class="clsrng"></div> first div remove click on first <span class="clsrng">x</span>

Comment: and it should also remove the X span? or just the additional content?

Answer (score 1):

Simply we can delete div using jquery
for ex-

```
$("span.clsrng").click(function(){
    $(this).parent("div.clsrng").remove();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

First create `onclick` event on `X` and pass the current element into it and then find the parent on the basis of this element call `removeChild()`. Following is working demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="rang">
<div class="clsrng">
  <span class="spnrng">one</span>
  <span class="clsrng" onclick="remove(this)">x</span>
</div>
<div class="clsrng">
  <span class="spnrng">two</span>
  <span class="clsrng" onclick="remove(this)">x</span>
</div>
<div class="clsrng">
  <span class="spnrng">three</span>
  <span class="clsrng" onclick="remove(this)">x</span>
</div>
</div>
<script>
var remove = function(data){
 var div = data.parentElement;
 if(div){
     div.parentElement.removeChild(div);
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the closest "Div" parent and remove that element.  Try this code :

```
$(".clsrng").click(function() {
$(this).closest("div.clsrng").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a unique `id` for every element and have a function for setting their display to none. Here's a demo of a complete page with the desired functionality.

```html
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Remove a div demo</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <script>
          function hideElement(elementId) {
            var element = document.querySelector(elementId);
    
            if (element) {
              element.style.display = "none";
            }
          }
        </script>
    
        <div id="rang">
          <div id="something1" class="clsrng">
            <span class="spnrng">one</span><span class="clsrng" onclick="hideElement('#something1')">x</span>
          </div>
          <div id="something2" class="clsrng">
            <span class="spnrng">two</span><span class="clsrng" onclick="hideElement('#something2')">x</span>
          </div>
          <div id="something3" class="clsrng">
            <span class="spnrng">three</span><span class="clsrng" onclick="hideElement('#something3')">x</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("body").on("click",".clsrng",function() {
     $(this).closest("div.clsrng").remove();
});
```

Comment: @aparna rai try this answer, i hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".clsrng").on("click",function(){
    $(this).closest("div").find("span").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rang">
<div class="clsrng"><span class="spnrng">one</span><span class="clsrng">x</span></div>
<div class="clsrng"><span class="spnrng">two</span><span class="clsrng">x</span></div>
<div class="clsrng"><span class="spnrng">three</span><span class="clsrng">x</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2mcdbs4c/

With the following function:

```
function removeSpan(el){
  var parent = el.parentElement;
  parent.parentElement.removeChild(parent);
}
```

We select the parent element and then removes it.

Then you can just add it as a onclick event on your element

```
onclick="removeSpan(this)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myFunc(id)
            {
                 var elem = document.getElementById(id);
      return elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="rang">
<div class="clsrng"><span class="spnrng" id="a1" onClick="myFunc(this.id);">one<span class="clsrng">x</span></span></div>
<div class="clsrng" ><span class="spnrng" id="a2" onClick="myFunc(this.id);">two<span class="clsrng">x</span></span></div>
<div class="clsrng" ><span class="spnrng" id="a3" onClick="myFunc(this.id);">three<span class="clsrng">x</span></span></div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clsrng').click(function(){
      $(this).remove();
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="rang">
<div class="clsrng"><span class="spnrng">one</span><span class="clsrng">x</span></div>
<div class="clsrng"><span class="spnrng">two</span><span class="clsrng">x</span></div>
<div class="clsrng"><span class="spnrng">three</span><span class="clsrng">x</span></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

you can simply use the remove() function of JQuery to do this, let me show you the example below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="rang">
<div class="clsrng"><span class="spnrng">one</span><span class="clsrng">x</span></div>
<div class="clsrng"><span class="spnrng">two</span><span class="clsrng">x</span></div>
<div class="clsrng"><span class="spnrng">three</span><span class="clsrng">x</span></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.clsrng').click(function(){
                $(this).remove();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//using javascript
var a =  document.querySelectorAll("span.clsrng");
for(i of a){
i.addEventListener('click',function(e){
e.currentTarget.parentNode.remove();
})
}
```

```html
<div id="rang">
<div class="clsrng"><span class="spnrng">one</span><span class="clsrng">x</span></div>
<div class="clsrng"><span class="spnrng">two</span><span class="clsrng">x</span></div>
<div class="clsrng"><span class="spnrng">three</span><span class="clsrng">x</span></div>
</div>
```