# click a button to delete itself and its parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, dynamic

--- UPDATED QUESTION ---

Thanks for all the answers. I wrote the JS code to delete the parent div when clicking its corresponding button in my **JS PRACTICE**!!!

However, the same JS code does not work in my real JS project where all the parent div are created dynamically. The complete code can be found below.

There is no error but the JS code just does not work. Any ideas?

BELOW IS THE SIMPLIFIED **REAL JS PROJECT ** COMPLETE CODE

```
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Upload Imgs</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    .container {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .display-area {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      flex-wrap: wrap;

    }

    img {
      max-width: 100%;

    }

    .image-preview {
      width: 80%;
      min-height: 300px;
      border: 2px dashed #dddddd;
      display: block;

      /*default text*/
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #cccccc;
    }


    .newbtns {
      border: 0;
      background: lightgrey;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px white;
      border: 1px solid #999;
      position: absolute;
      display: block;

    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id='inputFiles'><input type="file" class="file" name="image_uploads" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg"
        multiple></div>

    <div class="display-area" id='imgDisplay'>
    </div>
    <div id="defaultContent">
      <p>No images</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" value="Reload page" onclick="window.location.reload()">Reload Page</button>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>

<script>
  var input = document.querySelector('input');
  var uploadBox = document.getElementById('uploadBox');
  var defaultContent = document.getElementById('defaultContent');
  var imgDisplay = document.getElementById('imgDisplay')

  //upload & preview
  input.addEventListener('change', function () {
    var imgFiles = input.files;
    defaultContent.style.display = 'none';
    for (var i = 0; i < imgFiles.length; i++) {
      var imgDiv = document.createElement('div');
      imgDiv.className = 'imgBox';
      imgDiv.id = 'box' + i;
      imgDiv.style.width = "20%";
      var images = document.createElement('img');
      images.src = URL.createObjectURL(imgFiles[i]);
      var newbtn = document.createElement("button");
      newbtn.type = "button";
      newbtn.className = "newbtns";
      newbtn.innerHTML = "X";
      newbtn.style.color = "orange";
      newbtn.style.background = 'red';
      newbtn.id = 'newbtn' + i;
      imgDiv.appendChild(newbtn);
      imgDiv.appendChild(images);
      imgDisplay.appendChild(imgDiv);
    }
  });

  allButtons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  for (var n = 0; n < allButtons.length; n++) {

    if (allButtons[n].getAttribute('id') === 'newbtn' + n) {

      allButtons[n].onclick = function () {
        this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
      }

    } else { };

  }

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] which shows what you've done to try and solve this problem. Visit [ask] for more info

Comment: -> JavaScript: Find Parent of self and remove / hide DOM-Node.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove DIV tag using Javascript or Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755546/remove-div-tag-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: Roughly, `imgdispareaRef.removeChild(clickedButtonRef.parentNode)`.

Comment: The fastest thing is to put the CSS property `display` to `none` on the div `<div id='box1'>`

Comment: thanks. I just updated my question with the complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```js
const buttonOne = document.getElementById('btn1');
const buttonTwo = document.getElementById('btn2');


buttonOne.addEventListener("click", () => deleteElementAndThisChildNodes('box1'))
buttonTwo.addEventListener("click", () => deleteElementAndThisChildNodes('box2'))

function deleteElementAndThisChildNodes(parentId) {
  document.getElementById(parentId).remove()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I successfully wrote the JS code to delete the parent div in my practice js file while the same js code does not work in my real js project. I have listed both code above. And idea why?

Comment: Hi @smallwhite , the problem is that you don't defined the "reloadPage()" function, I made a litle simplification of your code to iterate between buttons here https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-agnesi-st1y9

Comment: Oops... I  just defined 'reloadPage()' function... but the problem is about other dynamically created buttons... my js code does not work for them... when I clicked the dynamically created button on the image, it does not delete its corresponding parent div...

Comment: I do an refactor to do what you need, basicaly, I set a for to  fun a function 5 times, this function create a button inside a parent div, and to any button add a eventListener to delete their parent. https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-agnesi-st1y9

Comment: thanks!!! I finally figured it out!!! It had something to do with the sequence of the code. now my code works well!!  ;)

Comment: Perfect, if my question help you,  you can upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

To each of your button elements add onclick="DeleteParent(this)" then outside of your dynamic divs include the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function DeleteParent(button){
          button.parentElement.remove();
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```js
const display = document.getElementById("imgdisplayarea");

display.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if(e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON'){
  //if an element within a display div for a button, remove your father
    e.target.parentNode.remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks. my js code can delete the static divs when clicking the button inside that div but not dynamically created ones... any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example that works exactly how you want it (based on your question):

```js
function disable() {
document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
<button onclick="disable()">
Click Me
</button>
<h3>
This is part of the div
</h3>
</div>
```